# How to enable pdo_mysql in Azure?

Tags: php, azure, pdo, azure-web-app-service

I'm buildig a simple web application in Laravel 8 using PHP 7.4 and Azure web services. The app runs perfectly on my local machine, but once I try to push my app to Azure I'm getting a PHP 500 error for all pages where some sort of querying is needed.

It turns out that I'm missing a pdo_mysql driver that hasn't been enabled when setting up our Linux server. I've been looking through all the Azure documentation and I can't seem to find how to turn this pdo extension on.

Strange thing is Azure provides us two terminals: the SSH terminal and a Bash terminal (Kudo remote execution terminal). When I run

> php -m

in the SSH, the pdo_mysql module does show up in the list. I can also migrate my tables within the SSH. But once I run the same

> php -m

command in the Bash terminal, the module is not showing. Migrating tables in that terminal is also not possible, because it says I'm missing the pdo_mysql driver. The Oryxbuilder that builds my application after each git deployment also notices that I'm missing the pdo_mysql driver and returns the same error.

So how can I enable this module in Azure? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i'd check to see if its enabled in the php.ini file, often located at /etc/php/{version}/cli/php.ini , `cli` may also be `cgi` or `apache2`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @smoothbean, I checked the php.ini files in both terminals. In the Kudo terminal the module is commented out and I can't edit that file due to the restrictions in that terminal. In the SSH the pdo_mysql module isn't commented out as I expected.